# jQuery load - keeps adding new file to resource tab in inspector

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following piece of code called every 30 seconds in order to update some information on my page;

```
$("#refreshblock").load("update.txt");
```

`update.txt` contains a small amount of text (~3Kb) that gets loaded into the div, and the `update.txt` file is updated by some backend scripts.

This all works fine and the page gets updated correctly. However if I view the `Resources` tab of the Inspector in my browser (Safari) under `XHRs` it shows a growing number of entries for the file `update.txt` – one for each time the jQuery is called.

This page is designed to be left open and running for prolonged periods. My question is are those entries swallowing up memory or storage on the users system and will continue to grow swallowing up ~3Kb every 30 seconds, or are those entries just for debugging and the system will clear the storage/memory used from those AJAX loads periodically. I know they are definitely all being stored for some length of time rather than it just logging the a resource was loaded as you can click each item in the Inspector and see the contents of the different update messages `update.txt` contained.

Comment: I suppose this depends on the Browser rather than the system. I don't have a Safari under hand right now, but you can test it with a sample page that adds a much bigger .txt file each 30 seconds, and monitor the memory usage.. Keep it the same delay you will use, that might have an influence

Comment: @Kaddath That's something I'll try later. It's not a browser specific thing though as the same occurs on Firefox and Chromes Inspector under the relevant sections for viewing XHR resources (Firefox lists them under Network for example).

Comment: The debug tools are similar, but the way the Browser keep things in memory may be much different from one to another. In Firefox's network, you see the requests made, which doesn't mean it keeps a ressource in memory for each call (it actually cannot retreive past calls made if the debugguer was closed during them, so having the dev console open actually influences the behaviour a lot -speed slowings in Firefox for example-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading the resource, It will continue to swallow user's traffic, but if you do not store it on something special - like local storage it won't hurt. Also if you load the contents of the file into the DOM, just make sure you are removing the old DOM elements, thus not leading to infinite load of DOM elements.

Also make sure that jquery is not returning the same file again and again, by using the [cache control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).
As a side note, if you use chrome - you can check in resource usages over time - for reference follow the link - [google's developer pages](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)